# Compare entries in columns from CSV files and extract matched - python

Tags: python, csv, compare, hash

I have two CSV files (three columns) which I need to compare and extract rows from other file (five columns) that matches. The example for files are:

File1:

```
ATGCGCGACAGT, ch3, 123546
ATGCATACAGGATAT, ch2, 5141561615
```

......so on approx 100 entries

File2:

```
ATGCGGCGACAGT,ch3, 123456,mi141515, AUCAGCUAUAUAU, UACGCAGAUAUAUA
ATCAGACGATTATGA, ch4, 4564764, mi653453, AUCAGCAAUUUUCG, AUACAGACAAAAA
```

....so on approx 50000 entries

I need to match the column 1,2 and 3 for both the files in such a way that all three columns of file1 should match with file2. If so happens than extract 4,5 and 6 columns for further processing.

I was thinking of:

```
fhout=csv.writer(open('parsed_out', 'w'), delimiter=',')

for i in file1:

     a=[0]
     b=[1]
     c=[2]
      for x in file2:
       d=[0]
       e=[1]
       f=[2]
       g=[3]
       h=[4]
       i=[5]
         if a==d and b==e and c==f:
           fhout.writerow([g]+[h]+[i])
         else:
           pass
```

But somebody told me that I can use hashing or some better way rather writing such big loops for 10,000 or more entries in file1

Please suggest me better way to achieve this. Both file 1 and file 2 are parsed from more complex files.

Comment: You could try loading the data into some sqlite tables and then joining them on the columns you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import csv

file_1_tuples = []

with open("file_1.csv") as fh:
    csv_reader = csv.reader ( fh )
    for row in csv_reader:
        file_1_tuples.append(  tuple(row)  )

with open("file_2.csv") as fh:
    csv_reader = csv.reader ( fh )
    for row in csv_reader:
        if tuple(row[0:3]) in file_1_tuples:
            print ( row[3:6] )
```

When run with the following data:

`file_1.csv`

```
person, john, smith
person, anne, frank
person, bob, macdonald
fruit, orange, banana
fruit, strawberry, fields
fruit, ringring, banana
```

`file_2.csv`

```
person, john, smith, 1, 2, 3
person, anne, frank, 4, 5, 6
person, bob, macdonald, 7, 8, 9
```

it produces the output

```
[' 1', ' 2', ' 3']
[' 4', ' 5', ' 6']
[' 7', ' 8', ' 9']
```

**EDIT:** A slightly nicer implementation using sets and list comprehensions:

```
import csv, pprint

with open("file_1.csv") as fh:
    csv_reader = csv.reader ( fh )
    file_1_tuples = { tuple(row) for row in csv_reader }

with open("file_2.csv") as fh:
    csv_reader = csv.reader ( fh )
    matched_rows = [ row for row in csv_reader if (tuple(row[:3]) in file_1_tuples)]

pprint.pprint (matched_rows)
```

**EDIT 2:** Note that this implementation is sensitive to the whitespace within the CSV file. If the spacing in your CSV file is inconsistent, use something like `row = [element.strip(' ') for element in row]` to strip out all the spaces.

Comment: why in file2 a tuple is made from 0-3 to match with file_1_tuples? Shouldn't it be 0-2? That is first three elements of file 2 matching with tuples from file1.

Comment: @AtulKakrana : when slicing arrays in Python, the start index is included but the *end index is not.* i.e. for `a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]`, `a[0:2]` only gives `[10,20]`. Either `a[0:3]` or `a[:3]` will give the first three elements `[10,20,30]`.

Answer (score 4):

Below creates a hash using a set comprehension for the first file as you suggest:

```
S = {tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(File1)}
```

Then when reading the second file the lookups are much faster.

```
for line in csv.reader(File2):
    key = tuple(line[:3])
    if key in S:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the fields from file 1 in a tuple and then add each tuple to a set. You can then perform containment testing on the first three fields in file 2 on the set, which is much faster than your hypothetical implementation.

Comment: @Abrahms: Thanks for helping. Could you please elaborate? File1: All three fields for a row make a tuple. I didn't followed after that. My programming level could be best described as beginner.

Comment: When you parse a line with will be in the form `[a, b, c]`, which is a `list`. Passing it to the `tuple` constructor will turn it into a `tuple`. `sometuple = tuple(somelist)`

Comment: See my answer for an implementation of @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams idea. (Using a list instead of the probably more-efficient set, but you get the idea.)